# how can I configure a specifc url for azure static websites?

Tags: azure

I'm currently working on a website for a client which is hosted as a static website on Azure.  The base url looks like this:

https://myclientcompany.z22.web.core.windows.net/

I'd like to configure the url to be structured like this:

interim.myclientcompany.com/

The "interim" subdomain represents a lower test/staging environment.  My client already owns the myclientcompany.com domain.  So what steps do I need to take in order to configure a setup where a user can use a url of interim.myclientcompany.com as an alias for the default Azure static website url provided in my post above?

Answer (score 1):

Detailed instructions about mapping a custom domain to a static website is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#mapping-a-custom-domain-to-a-static-website-url.